# Get popular posts with JSON feed on Blogger

Tags: json, blogger

I am aware of the widget for popular posts, but I want to create my own. The widget doesn't allow me to access (for example) the body of the post, only title, snippet, URL and thumbnail.

Is there a way to get view count with JSON feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feed of the popular posts, nor is the "count" public data that can be accessed via the normal feeds.

You can still manipulate the existing LI elements that are outputted, for instance [creating a slideshow](http://www.blogxpertise.com/2013/04/transforming-blogger-popular-post-widget-slideshow.html)